# Python parsing 'True' and 'False' as strings

Tags: python, parsing, boolean

Is there a way in python to parse the string `'True'` as `True` (boolean) and `'False'` as `False` (boolean)?

I know I could do `bool('True')` or `bool('False')` but each would be `True`

Comment: Take a look at `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: Can’t test because I’m on my phone, can you use eval()?

Comment: Look at @Austin's answer.

Comment: Why not simply use `string == 'True'`?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('False')
False
```

If you do `type(ast.literal_eval('False'))`, you see `<class 'bool'>`:

```
>>> type(ast.literal_eval('False'))
<class 'bool'>
```

---

You could also write your own function that returns `'True'` as boolean `True`, `'False'` as boolean `False` and if you supply any other input, it returns the same back:

```
def parse(string):
    d = {'True': True, 'False': False}
    return d.get(string, string)
```

Now, you call as:

```
>>> parse('True')
True
>>> parse('False')
False
>>> parse('Anything')
'Anything'
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would not recommend `ast.literal_eval` or `eval`. The best thing to do is probably this:

```
def parse_boolean(b):
    return b == "True"
```

`"True"` will return `True` and `"False"` will return `False`.